# Get date in date format from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have a table in SQL Server with a `date` column set to default date, however, when I fetch the data from the server using VBA I get the date column in string format. Is there any way I get the date as in date format?

Comment: Fetch and convert string to date format. This is suggestion because I am not aware of VBA.

Comment: Dates have no format. They are binary values. VBA also has dates, in fact strongly-typed date parameters were used with VBA and VB6. If you have formatting issues post your code

Comment: In fact, given that VBA can't create standalone applications, where do you use it? In Excel, values are formatted at the cell level. If you display a date value what you see will follow the cell's format. The *same* value can be displayed in different ways simply by changing the format from the cell's properties

Comment: Maybe [FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp) or [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the datetime in your SQL to the ISO8601 ('yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ') format?

Comment: @LukStorms VBA can read date values - always could. Dates are formattted by the *application* (Excel, Word etc) so hard-coding a format will only make things worse

Answer (score 0):

Can you you advise how you are bringing in the data? EG from inbuilt connectors or via a recordset via VBA objects?

A quick hack which I wouldn't advise without really testing would be this :

> Select  DateDiff(DD, '1899-12-30', date_column) AS [column] from TABLE_x

What is this doing?  
In Excel dates start 01-01-1900. When you change a date to 'General' you find it's actually a number with a format. The above date difference will give you the excel number version of the Date.

EG to get today 29/11/2019 which will be 43798 when cell format is 'General'.

> Select  DateDiff(DD, '1899-12-30', '2019-11-29') AS [column]

More info here
 
[Non MS site explaining the situation](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/)
 
[MS Office Info touching on the subject](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

 Please note this basing your question on a SQL formatted date.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am using ado connection, my sql query is SELECT * FROM TABLENAME

Comment: Hey. So we use something similar and it’s mainly fine. One thing is if you are adding the data into row 2 (eg under column names) that it might be best to select the whole column and chose date format. Excel will check the first couple of rows and define the format for the rest of the column. Also possibly , just select whole column in vba and then doing text to columns. It re-asserts the data as it does converts.